# There is extra space at the bottom and on the right of my site when on mobile

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, vite

[The extra space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uHMu.png)

For some reason I have some extra space at the bottom and to the right but both my body and my root end where the twitch logo is so it should only scroll til there, and I want to only be able to scroll til there.

This is my `ComingSoon.jsx`:

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const ComingSoon = () => {
  const nav = useNavigate();
  return (
    <div className="min-h-screen min-w-fit align-middle justify-center">
      <div className="relative p-5 right-8 xl:right-19rem xxl:right-38rem 3xl:right-83.5rem 3xl:w-screen bg-red-600 xl:w-95vw">
        {/* <p className="relative text-9xl text-center text-white">Coming Soon</p> */}
        <img
          src="/src/Imgs/logo.png"
          className="relative xl:w-50rem xl:left-32rem xl:h-5rem"
        />
        <button
          className="relative w-32 mx-2 p-2 top-2 xxl:text-5xl xxl:w-72 text-white hover:w-36 hover:mx-0  hover:shadow-lg hover:bg-white hover:text-black hover:rounded"
          onClick={() => nav("/about")}
        >
          About us
        </button>
        <button
          className="relative w-32 mx-2 p-2 top-2 xxl:text-5xl xxl:w-72 text-white hover:w-36 hover:mx-0  hover:shadow-lg hover:bg-white hover:text-black hover:rounded"
          onClick={() => nav("/critics")}
        >
          {/* eslint-disable-next-line react/no-unescaped-entities */}
          Game Critic's
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="relative w-screen left-10 h-32rem bg-mobilecs bg-contain bg-no-repeat xl:bg-comingsoon xl:h-38rem xxl:h-50rem xl:-left-72 xl:top-16 xxl:-left-38rem xxl:top-32 3xl:-left-80rem 3xl:h-80rem 3xl:top-64" />
      <p className="relative right-32 top-2 xl:right-72 xl:top-20 text-white xxl:text-2xl xxl:right-38rem xxl:top-22rem 3xl:text-5xl 3xl:right-80rem 3xl:top-28rem">
        In the meantime you can also check out:
      </p>
      <p className="relative right-32 top-2 xl:right-72 xl:top-20 text-white xxl:text-2xl xxl:right-38rem xxl:top-22rem 3xl:text-5xl 3xl:right-80rem 3xl:top-28rem">
        Trisp
      </p>
      <a
        className="relative right-32 top-2 xl:right-72 xl:top-20 xxl:text-2xl xxl:right-38rem xxl:top-22rem 3xl:text-5xl 3xl:right-80rem 3xl:top-28rem"
        href="https://www.twitch.tv/trisp"
        target="_blank"
        rel="noopener noreferrer"
      >
        <button className="text-white">
          <img
            className="h-10 w-10 xxl:h-16 xxl:w-16 3xl:h-32 3xl:w-32"
            src="./src/Imgs/twitchlogo.webp"
          />
        </button>
      </a>
      <a
        className="relative right-32 top-2 xl:right-72 xl:top-20 xxl:text-2xl xxl:right-38rem xxl:top-22rem 3xl:text-5xl 3xl:right-80rem 3xl:top-28rem"
        href="https://www.youtube.com/@Trisp."
        target="_blank"
        rel="noopener noreferrer"
      >
        <button className="text-white">
          <img
            className="h-10 w-10 xxl:h-16 xxl:w-16 3xl:h-32 3xl:w-32"
            src="./src/Imgs/youtubelogo.webp"
          />
        </button>
      </a>
      <iframe
        className="absolute opacity-0 -right-52 xl:top-28"
        src="https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=trisp&parent=playerreviewedgames.com&muted=true"
        height="440"
        width="790"
        allowfullscreen
      ></iframe>
    </div>
  );
};
export default ComingSoon;
```

Also my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Player Reviewed Games</title>
  </head>
  <body class="bg-dark-blue box-border top-0 left-0 right-0 bottom-0 overflow-y-scroll overflow-x-hidden ">
    <div id="root" class=""></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried fixed I tried overflow hidden I tried anything but they don't seem to work and I am not sure what to do.

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with tailwind-css or vite, but the <iframe> inside of the <div> with a absolute dimensions of `height="440"` and `width="790"` seems like it could be part of the issue.  If you temporarily remove that do things look more normal?

Comment: Yes I looked at it and it seemed to be the issue... So I kinda like gave it a top of 0 and it worked... Ut was basically dragging everything down and for some reason it wouldn't show up for me so I was just getting confused.